# Finding historical sector p/e ratio averages

Tags: market-data

I'm making an algorithm that takes p/e ratio into account. To do this, I need to give it perspective of the entire sector's p/e ratio. Is there a source of historical sector wide p/e ratio averages? If not, how could I calculate it using the p/e ratio of individual stocks?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess this might be the best choice. I haven’t found any websites that offer the sector p/e so i’ll just calculate it. Also, what are sector-mover companies?

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you very much.